# Mountain Lion Free Upgrade Issue

Tags: upgrade, macos, mac-appstore

I have bought my mac last month, so I am eligible to get a free upgrade of Mountain Lion. As Apple stated - I have requested for my upgrade and it said you will be notified with your upgrade code. It's been 24+ hours and I have not received any mail from Apple.
So, how much time they're taking to send a mail usually?

Thanks

EDIT - There was some technical issue with the form on saturday. I called Apple Care and they've sent me the codes now.

Thank you all for help.
Ak

Comment: Also, don't expect it to be as quick on weekends as other times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code came just 2 hours after the request, although it didn't work (was already used once)

Just write them an email to uptodatesupport-de@apple.com and ask them there. I wrote them an email after getting the wrong code and they replied with a new code within a day.

Answer (score 2):

Mine took about 3 days. The entire thing has been a bit of a shambles to be honest. I'd give them another couple of days then just get in touch with them.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Support in Moscow said that it can take around 72 hours (I've got my after 3 days of waiting).

Answer (score 1):

Check your spam folder too, in case it got sent there.

You should get two emails from noreply@apple.com, one with a pdf containing the code and one with a password to open the pdf (obviously, to the email that you used to on the up-to-date page).

And as others have said, it takes three days, and that probably won't include Saturday or Sunday.